# css form alignment with span

Tags: html, css

I have a form with 11 input/text fields. The first field has a `<span>` next to it, as displayed in the picture below. How can I adjust my css so that the span element doesn't push everything to the left? I want the input label and box to appear inline with the rest of the items.

Here are my CSS and HTML codes:

```css
form {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

label {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100px;
}

span {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expeses__container">

  <h3>Monthly Expenses</h3>

  <form>

    <label for="rent">Sales Tax Rate (Enter State)</label>

    <input type="text" name="rent" id="rent" />

    <span class="tax__rate">Avg Rate: 10%</span><br />

    <label> Rent/Mortgage</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Car</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Groceries</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Bills</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Subscription(s)</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Entertainment</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Credit Card</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Student Loans</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Child Care</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <label>Other</label>

    <input type="text" /><br />

    <section class="total_income">

      <span class="final_total--income">$0</span>

      <h2 class="section-heading">Total Per Month</h2>

    </section>

  </form>

</div>
```

[image: form not aligning]

Comment: https://freefrontend.com/css-forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Table HTML Element

You can use a `table` with 11 rows and 3 columns and style the `table` as you wish or you can have 3 `div` elements right next to each other as columns.

Below code shows how you can do that using a `table`:

```css
form {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
}

span {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expeses__container">
  <h3>Monthly Expenses</h3>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="rent">Sales Tax Rate (Enter State)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="rent" id="rent" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="tax__rate">Avg Rate: 10%</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Rent/Mortgage</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Car</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Groceries</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Bills</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Subscription(s)</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Entertainment</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <section class="total_income">
      <span class="final_total--income">$0</span>
      <h2 class="section-heading">Total Per Month</h2>
    </section>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Using Flexbox and Grid Layout

Without using `table`, you need to structure your `label`, `input` and `span` elements into 3 columns of `div` elements. These `div` elements will be inside of a container and the container can be styled using both [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [CSS Flexbox Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and creating a HTML structure similar to `table`.

Below code shows how you can do that using flexbox layout:

```css
form {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  /*
   * Instead of settig input's width to fixed value (100px)
   * we will set it to 100% and box-sizing to border-box
   * to prevent overflowing due to border and padding of input
   */
  /* width: 100px; */
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-group {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.form-group__label {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}

.form-group__input {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.form-group__info{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="expeses__container">
  <h3>Monthly Expenses</h3>
  <form>
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group__label">
          <label for="rent">Sales Tax Rate (Enter State)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group__input">
          <input type="text" name="rent" id="rent" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group__info">
          <span class="tax__rate">Avg Rate: 10%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group__label">
          <label>Rent/Mortgage</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group__input">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group__label">
          <label>Car</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group__input">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group__label">
          <label>Groceries</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group__input">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="total_income">
      <span class="final_total--income">$0</span>
      <h2 class="section-heading">Total Per Month</h2>
    </section>
  </form>
</div>
```

Below code shows hwo you can do that with grid layout:

```css
form {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  /*
   * Instead of settig input's width to fixed value (100px)
   * we will set it to 100% and box-sizing to border-box
   * to prevent overflowing due to border and padding of input
   */
  /* width: 100px; */
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.form-container {
  display: grid;
}

.form-group {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(100% / 3) 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="expeses__container">
  <h3>Monthly Expenses</h3>
  <form>
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <label for="rent">Sales Tax Rate (Enter State)</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="rent" id="rent" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="tax__rate">Avg Rate: 10%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <label>Rent/Mortgage</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <label>Car</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <label>Groceries</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="total_income">
      <span class="final_total--income">$0</span>
      <h2 class="section-heading">Total Per Month</h2>
    </section>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Do you mind sharing some code for what the flexbox option would look like? Im new to css :)

Comment: @aero8991 Yeah, sure thing. I'll update this answer tomorrow with flexbox and grid versions of code. Enjoy your learning experience, hope to see you in a good position in the future :)

Comment: @aero8991 Hey, I just updated the codes with flexbox and grid layouts. Truth is that we can accomplish same styling with many other ways like using, we could even use only 2 inline-divs inside a div without needing to use table or advanced layouts like grid or flexbox. There're many ways to accomplish a syling in CSS.

Comment: thanks for this! I really appreciate your feedback.